# Bind9 Response Policy Zone (RPZ), does not work on clients

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

On my *single* DNS server, **bind9** (**version 9.11.5-P4-5.1**), I have configured a *Response Policy Zone (RPZ)* to block certain domains. The IP of the DNS server is **192.168.1.5**

Now I am going to put the relevant parts to the configuration of the different files and commands:

On the server:

In **/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

```
acl trusted {
    localhost; # this server
    192.168.1.0/24; #my net
}
```

Also

```
// Only allows trusted client to use the service
allow-query { trusted; };

forwarders {
    The IP of the NS1 of IPS#1;
    The IP of the NS2 of IPS#1;
    The IP of the NS1 of IPS#2;
    The IP of the NS2 of IPS#2;
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;
    1.1.1.1;
};
```

And also

```
    // For Ad-Blocking/Blacklisting/Whitelisting
    response-policy {
        zone "rpz.blacklist";
        zone "office.local" policy passthru;
        zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" policy passthru;
    };
```

In **/etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
  zone "rpz.blacklist" {
      typemaster;
      file "/etc/bind/zones/rpz.blacklist.db";
      allow-query { trusted; };
      allow-transfer { localhost; };
  };
```

And finally in **/etc/bind/zones/rpz.blacklist.db**

```
  ; BIND reverse data file for empty rfc1918 zone
  ;
  ; DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is used for multiple zones.
  ; Instead, copy it, edit named.conf, and use that copy.
  ;
  $TTL 86400
  @ IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
  1     ; Serial
  604800; Refresh
  86400; Retry
  2419200; expire
  86400); Negative Cache TTL
  ;

  @ IN NS localhost.

  ;.:#====================#:.
  ; Blacklist Domains
  ;.:#====================#:.

  ads2000.hw.net IN A 127.0.0.1
```

There are more domains but I leave one only for the example.

The commands [**named-checkconf**] and [**named-checkconf "rpz.blacklist" /etc/bind/zones/rpz.blacklist.db**] return OK and the service starts successfully

Now if I ping ads2000.hw.net from the same server **it works fine**

```
  ping -c 5 ads2000.hw.net
  PING ads2000.hw.net (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
  64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
  64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
  64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.201 ms
  64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms

  --- ads2000.hw.net ping statistics ---
  5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 105ms
  rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.034/0.069/0.201/0.066ms
```

Now if I do it from a linux client, **it does not** :

```
  ping -c 5 ads2000.hw.net
  PING ads2000.hw.net (65.8.181.28) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from server-65-8-181-28.mia3.r.cloudfront.net (65.8.181.28): icmp_seq=1 ttl=246 time=131 ms
    64 bytes from server-65-8-181-28.mia3.r.cloudfront.net (65.8.181.28): icmp_seq=2 ttl=246 time=131 ms
    64 bytes from server-65-8-181-28.mia3.r.cloudfront.net (65.8.181.28): icmp_seq=3 ttl=246 time=131 ms
    64 bytes from server-65-8-181-28.mia3.r.cloudfront.net (65.8.181.28): icmp_seq=4 ttl=246 time=131 ms
    64 bytes from server-65-8-181-28.mia3.r.cloudfront.net (65.8.181.28): icmp_seq=5 ttl=246 time=131 ms
```

This is my dns settings on that computer

```
  cat /etc/resolv.conf
  ## Generated by NetworkManager
  domain office.local
  search office.local
  nameserver 192.168.1.5
  nameserver 1.1.1.1
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Now if I do it from a windows client, **it does not work either**:

```
  ping ads2000.hw.net
  Ping ads2000.hw.net [65.8.181.28] with 32 bytes of data:
  Response from 65.8.181.28: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=246
  Response from 65.8.181.28: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=246
  Response from 65.8.181.28: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=246
  Response from 65.8.181.28: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=246
  Ping statistics for 65.8.181.28:
      Packets: sent = 4, received = 4, lost = 0
(0% lost),
  Approximate round trip times in milliseconds:
Minimum = 131ms, Maximum = 131ms, Average = 131ms
```

This is my dns settings on that computer

```
   Ethernet Ethernet Adapter:
      Specific DNS suffix for the connection. . : office.local
      DNS servers. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5
                                          1.1.1.1
                                          8.8.8.8
```

If I remove the servers "**1.1.1.1**" and "**8.8.8.8**" from the clients, it works but from them I lose Internet

What am I doing wrong?

I thank you in advance for your help.

**PS: Sorry for my bad English**

**PS 2:**

They told me not to use ping and to use dig.

I have discovered something new from a comment that was made to me, and **it also fails me on the same server** when using dig, instead of putting @localhost, I put @192.168.1.5 (which is the ip of my server)

With the IP

```
dig @192.168.1.5 ads2000.hw.net

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u2-Debian <<>> @192.168.1.5 ads2000.hw.net
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

With localhost

```
dig @localhost ads2000.hw.net

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u2-Debian <<>> @localhost ads2000.hw.net
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21521
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 2ce3f4f1d313ffad11763e9a623e3a8023aa719aef8f2ec4 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ads2000.hw.net.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ads2000.hw.net.         5       IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 433 msec
;; SERVER: :127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: vie mar 25 18:56:16 -03 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 87
```

Comment: ";; connection timed out; no servers could be reached" means your server at 192.168.1.5 can not be reached at all from where you try (and hence clients will go use next possible resolver), so you should fix that. Check firewall rules and routing after checking on the server itself that it is indeed running on listening on the given IP address. DNS needs port 53 for both UDP and TCP.

Comment: The ports are open I have no firewall configured yet

    netstat -a -n |grep 53
    tcp        0      0 192.168.1.5:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: netstat -a -n |grep 53 |grep udp

    udp        0      0 192.168.1.5:53          0.0.0.0:*
    udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*
    udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*
    udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*
    udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*
Can apparmor or a permissive selinux block connections to 192.168.1.5 port 53?

Comment: Thanks to those who helped me.
I found the solution, starting with a freshly installed debian and configuring bit by bit.
The problem was not copying 100% of the dns server configuration, and I left the problem out.

In "named.conf.options" I had the following

acl bogusnets {
     ...192.168.0.0/16; ...
};
// Ban bogus networks
blackhole { bogusnets; };

With which it blocked my network of type C. Both from the clients and from the interface of the server itself with IP of the network. I removed that net and mask from that acl and it started working.

Regards.